# Custom "No Results"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar

I'm trying to display a custom no results when my array is equal 0 but for some reason its not working. If somebody can see my code:

```
if ([self.content count] == 0) {
    UIImageView *bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"detallesbackground123"]];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:bg];
} else {
    UILabel *verSee = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:7];
    [verSee setText:currentText];
    UILabel *verPa = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:17];
    [verPa setText:currentDe];
}
```

Comment: Where do you have this code?

Comment: Please take effort about question u r posting! Dont hesitate to describe clearly!! Bdw, if I got ur que, u want to show "no result found" when there is nothing in an array. If so, then just set title to single cell as "no result to found". And if its not what u want, edit ur question that will be more clear and easy to understand ur EXACT problem!

Comment: Not familiar with setBackgroundView: is this in a tableview subclass or class extension?

Comment: @danh, backgroundView is a property of UITableView.

Comment: I think the issue is, you are probably returning `[self.content count]` from your `numberOfRowsInSection` method. So if it is zero. your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

you seems to place your code in **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath**

however, if [self.content count] == 0 , your tableView won't ask for  **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath** because you don't have any datasource.

try set your code in **viewDidLoad**.or

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

if you have a NSFetchedResultsController fetches object from CoreData.